# Java script Counter

Tags: javascript

How to modify the application so that the counter in `#root` correctly displays and increments by one whenever the button is pressed:

```
import $ from "jquery";

const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = `<div id="mainArea">
  <p>button count: <span>0</span></p>
  <button id="mainButton">Increase</button>
</div>`;
```

Comment: There's no counter code here. Only code that dynamically creates a button and a place to show a counter. What have you tried?

Comment: Some basic research into how to create click event listeners how to access elements in the page and how to get and set text in those elements would at least get you started. Basic research is expected when asking questions on SO. Then ask questions when you have actual code attempts to solve your own situation that are not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You should look at eventListeners, variables and querySelectors in JavaScript:

[EventListeners in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

[QuerySelectors in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[GetElementById()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

But in your case, you could do this:

HTML-Code:

```
<div id="mainArea">
  <p>button count: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
  <button id="mainButton">Increase</button>
</div>
```

(Here I've added an ID to the counter to access it directly)

JavaScript-Code:

```
let counter = 0; // defining the counter number variable

document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click", () => { // creating the eventListener and the arrow function for it
  counter++; // increasing the counter variable by one
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter; // updating the counter span tag in our HTML
});
```

(I've used an arrow function in this example, here is the [MDN Post about that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

Without arrow functions:

```
let counter = 0; // defining the counter number variable

document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click", function() { // creating the eventListener and the function for it
  counter++; // increasing the counter variable by one
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter; // updating the counter span tag in our HTML
```

Please learn the JavaScript basics and stick to references like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Minor errors: Get rid of the # as part of the ID in the getElementById() settings.

Comment: Oh, sorry, was a little bit tired ':).